# Retina Macbook Pro with External Display (Samsung BX2440)

Tags: display, macbook-pro, hdmi

I have just switched to a rMBP from a Windows 7 laptop.  I use an external 24 inch monitor (Samsung BX2440) via the HDMI port on the rMBP.  It seems that due to some scaling, the text on the external monitor (particularly fixed width text) is a lot blurrier than what is was via my Windows machine.

[image: fixed width example]

Is there any way I can improve the text quality on the external display?  I've tried all of the standard things people have mentioned on forums.  The display is set to its native resolution (1080p) as per:

[image: display settings]

Neither Best for display nor Scaled at 1080p make a difference.

Will a Thunderbolt->DVI cable help at all?

Comment: I don't think that is your cable, your image looks like the text is being dithered.

Answer (score 1):

haven't tried myself, but according to this [blog post](https://chris.dziemborowicz.com/blog/2012/07/04/fix-external-monitor-resolution-on-macbook-pro-with-retina-display/) if you press option key when selection `Scaled` radio button, you will get more resolutions.

Comment: You're correct, but the OP states his native resolution was already available, which means it shouldn't be a resolution issue.